# Custom XML Elements for Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am writing a program that you can read multiple books. The book im trying to put in xml format to be easily referenced. To do this I created custom xml for android such as book and chapter. However by code is not compiling and showing the message 'com.merlee.myapplication2.BOOK'. Any suggestions or help? Here is the code for attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="BOOK">
    <attr name="bnumber" format="integer" />
    <attr name="bname" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Here is my code for the xml file:

```
<resources>
<com.merlee.myapplication2.BOOK >
    bnumber= "1"
    </com.merlee.myapplication2.BOOK>
</resources>
```

Comment: Have you ever seen XML? That's now how attributes are written. Please check an XML reference... or any other valid XML in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you declared xmlns in you xml file?

if you want to user the customed attribute in your xml,first you must declared it in your xml file,for example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:abc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

after that,you can use it

```
<com.merlee.myapplication2.BOOK >
abc:bnumber= 1
</com.merlee.myapplication2.BOOK>
```

Comment: what if the place where i declared book is not in myActivity?